# Don't show tabs in Emacs whitespace mode

Tags: emacs, text-editors, elisp, whitespace

Normally, I use spaces for indentation, but for a specific project I'm working on the convention is tabs for indentation. So I've made a `.dir-locals.el` file that looks like this:

```
((nil . ((indent-tabs-mode . t)
     (whitespace-style . '(face empty trailing lines-tail)))))
```

Before, whitespace-style was `(face tabs empty trailing lines-tail)`.

However, when I do this and load emacs, nothing changes. If I toggle `whitespace-mode` on and off, tabs aren't highlighted, but trailing spaces and other things that should be highlighted aren't highlighted either, almost like `whitespace-mode` is still off.

Am I doing something wrong? I'm using Emacs 24.3.1 on Arch Linux with [prelude](https://github.com/bbatsov/prelude).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the quote mark: `(face empty trailing lines-tail)` instead of `'(face empty trailing lines-tail)`.